# How to sort nested PHP array

Tags: php, sorting

Can anyone tell me how to sort an array by key?
I want to sort this array by price.

this is my input array format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [house_data] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 532
                    [max_person] => 8
                    [max_bedrooms] => 4
                )

            [image] => uploads/123.jpg
            [price] => 1950
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [house_data] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 531
                    [max_person] => 8
                    [max_bedrooms] => 5
                )

            [image] => uploads/1234.jpg
            [price] => 1495
        )
}
```

Comment: by single dimension you mean array(0 => "532, 8, 4, uploads/123.jpg, 1950", 1 => ....) ?

Comment: Give me your output format.

Comment: yeah aleation, how to do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) (http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

You should have something like:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['price'] == $b['price']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['price'] < $b['price']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($table, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `array_multisort()` function  for multidimensional array sorting.

Answer (score 0):

For making it one dimensional use serialize($array) function , it goes like this :
$a = array() ;  //your multidimensional array
$b = array();   //output array
foreach ($a as $key=>$value){
  $b[] = serialize($value);
}
echo $b ;